# How to group grep results?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file that contains results grouped into categories. For example:

```
checking results for $var
here are some results1 for $var status ok
here are some results2 for $var status ok
here are some results3 for $var status ok

checking results for $var2
here are some results1 for $var2 status ok

checking results for $var3
here are some results1 for $var3 status ok
here are some results2 for $var3 status ok
here are some results3 for $var3 status critical
here are some results4 for $var3 status ok
```

I need to check if any of the lines in a given category had status "critical", and display it if so. For example:

```
Status $var -- OK
Status $var2 -- OK
Status $var3 -- Critical

Note : Critial at $result3 for $var3
```

Using `grep -A` would not suit me much because the number of results under a particular variable varies.

Comment: Could you post an example of your input files? It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you have and what you want.

Comment: the example i posted is how the files are listed. at the end of the script i need to print out the $var status if its ok or critical.

Comment: Take a look at Ack http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: @afbr1201: still not very clear. I understand the type of output you are looking for, but not the format of the source. What you posted looks processed already (is that correct?). If that's the case, what's the format of the original data? (Might be easier to get what you want directly from there.)

Comment: @Mat : yeah, this is a processed output already., i don't have access from the backend (who parse this type of result)., so i can only parse this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk will do it:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        priority["ok"] = 10
        priority["critical"] = 20
    }
    /^$/ {next}
    /^checking/ {var = $NF}
    {
        if (priority[status[var]] < priority[$NF])
            status[var] = $NF
        if ($NF == "critical")
            crit[var ":" $4] = 1
    }
    END {
        for (var in status)
            print var, status[var]
        for (c in crit) {
            split(c, ary, /:/)
            printf("critical at %s for %s\n", ary[2], ary[1])
        }
    }
'
```

outputs

```
$var ok
$var2 ok
$var3 critical
critical at results3 for $var3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an awk script:

```awk
/^checking results for / {
    if (curvar) { print curvar, curstatus; }
    curvar = $NF
    curstatus = "ok"
}
/^here are some results.* for .* status / {
    if ($NF != "ok") { curstatus = $NF; 
}
END {
    if (curvar) { print curvar, curstatus; }
}
```

You could use an array to build up the "bad results" table.

Comment: missing a close brace on one of the `if` statements